# how do i set x y coordinates so that the image zooms onto that point when the imageview is opened?

Tags: android, android-layout, zooming, android-relativelayout, setfocus

I have a `static` Image of a Map and I want it to `focus/zoom` onto a specific point on the Map (for example when a user searches for a particular location).

So far this is how I got the Map `displaying`, `zooming` and `panning` and it works fine.

```
public class MapDisplayActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

private static final String TAG = "Touch";
// These matrices will be used to move and zoom image
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

// We can be in one of these 3 states
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

// Remember some things for zooming
PointF start = new PointF();
PointF mid = new PointF();
float oldDist = 1f;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.mappage);
  ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
  view.setOnTouchListener(this);
}
```

I'm using `RelativeLayout` for the `ImageView`.